# On-boarding slider screen

Tags: android, slider, screen, splash-screen

I have used a built in library to create "android on-boarding slider screen". The library is implementation 'com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.3'. The intro screen should open only first time when the app is launched but it opens everytime i run my app. How to launch is only the first time?

```
public class IntroActivity extends AppIntro {
private PrefManager prefManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance("First","This is the first page",
            R.drawable.sugar, ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorAccent)));
    addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance("Second","This is the second page",
            R.drawable.baseline_card_giftcard_black_24dp, ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.colorPrimary)));
    addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance("Third","This is the third page",
            R.drawable.baseline_fastfood_black_18dp, ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark)));
}

@Override
public void onDonePressed(Fragment currentFragment) {
    super.onDonePressed(currentFragment);
    Intent intent = new Intent(IntroActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onSkipPressed(Fragment currentFragment) {
    super.onSkipPressed(currentFragment);

    Intent intent = new Intent(IntroActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Comment: You need to save a variable say shouldShowOnboarding in the preference, and check the value on every launch.Once the onboarding screens are either skipped or completely seeb by the user update it to false.

Comment: The splash screen can decide if to open intro activity or any other screen based on the shouldShowonboarding preference value

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for the library, available [here](https://github.com/paolorotolo/AppIntro):

> Finally, declare the activity in your Manifest like so:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.example.intro"
android:label="@string/app_intro" />
```

> Do not declare the intro as your main app launcher unless you want the intro to launch every time your app starts. Refer to the wiki for an example of how to launch the intro once from your main activity.

This is what the [Wiki](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro/wiki/How-to-Use#show-the-intro-once) is referring to:

> If the above method is unclear or you're not able to implement the same, then try writing the following code which uses SharedPreferences in your MainActivity.java file:-

```
/* In your onCreate method */
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(MyPrefs, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (!sp.getBoolean("first", false)) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("first", true);
        editor.apply();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, IntroActivity.class); // Call the AppIntro java class
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

This code reads a shared preference, and if it is found to not exist, or if it's value is false, it creates or edits the preference (so that the condition fails next time) then opens the intro screen.

Comment: After 50 or so edits, this should be everything you need to sort it out.

Comment: Glad to help, don't forget to mark the question as answered if your problem was solved.